# Picking elements from a list Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have some trouble writing a function that will pick each element out of a list. What I want my function to do is take in a list, and return the element that was picked, and a new list without the element. The call to the function would look like the following:

```
   pickElement([LIST], PICKEDELEMENT, NEWLIST).
```

So if I passed in the list [1,2,3] I want the function to pass three times and the outputs look like the following:

```
   PICKEDELEMENT = 1
   NEWLIST = [2,3]

   PICKEDELEMENT = 2
   NEWLIST = [1,3]

   PICKEDELEMENT = 3
   NEWLIST = [1,3]
```

I wrote the following function but after it picks an element it takes it out of the list which I don't want.

```
   pickELEMENT([X|XREST],X,XREST).
   pickELEMENT([X|XREST],PICKEDELEMENT,NEWLIST) :- 
   pick(XREST,PICKEDELEMENT,NEWLIST).
```

I'm having a hard time getting the output that I am looking for. If anyone can show me what I need to do that would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You should be getting a singleton variable warning for variable `X`. This is a strong indicator that you're missing some logic related to this element; and in this case that is indeed so. Ask yourself: what should I do with the value this holds to get the expected output?

Comment: For what it's worth, this is a library function called [select/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=select%2f3) and you can [view its source code here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/lists.pl?show=src#select/3).

Comment: @Steven 
To include the X to make sense should I add it to the NEWLIST that is being returned?

Comment: @user7595741 Usually when you get a singleton, it either means you forgot how the variable relates to the rest of the rule or you should replace it with `_`. In this case, replacing it with `_` will cause it to be omitted from the result, so probably you should include it. You could also _just try it_ and see if it works. :)

Comment: @DanielLyons 
When I omit the X with _ I get the same result if I didn't omit it because I'm not using it for anything in the function. I've tried a bunch of variations but I can't seem to get what I'm looking for. Am I going in the right direction with this?

Comment: Look how similar your code is to the library code in my link above. You're close.

Comment: @DanielLyons 
I'm a doof. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is in the good direction. It contains some errors, for example you define a predicate `pickELEMENT/2`, but then aim to make a call to `pick/2`. With some "rewriting", we obtain the predicate you problaby wanted to implement:

```
pick([X|XRest], X, XRest).
pick([X|XRest], Element, NewList) :- 
    pick(XRest, Element, NewList).
```

Now there is still a semantical error: in your second clause the third parameter is `NewList`, so that means that we "ignore" the `X` in the original list. Yes, in your second clause you do not *pick* `X`, but this thus means that it should be part of the `NewList`, so we prepend the result of the recursive call with `X`, like:

```
pick([X|XRest], X, XRest).
pick([X|XRest], Element, [X|NewList]) :- 
    pick(XRest, Element, NewList).
```

The above can be improved, here we will unpack a "cons" list element twice: once in the first clause, and once in the second clause. We can prevent this inefficiency by implementing a `pick/4` predicate, and redirect `pick/3` to `pick/4` like:

```
pick([H|T], X, NewList) :-
    pick(T, H, X, NewList).

pick(XRest, X, X, XRest).
pick([X2|XRest], X, Element, [X|NewList]) :- 
    pick(XRest, X2, Element, NewList).
```